# Answered in the question

Tags: discussion, closing, game-identification

Originally, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201135/looking-for-an-old-ms-dos-game) was closed because it didn't have the required details for a [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) question. However, with a little perseverance, they did find the solution.

Should it be re-opened? The OP "answered" his question in the original question, due to his question being closed, so should it be re-opened to allow him to post it as the answer?